# Why is nodetool not running on my ccm cluster?

Tags: cassandra, ccm

im using ccm to learn some cassandra, im trying to use `ccm node1 nodetool status` and run into this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/ccm/3.1.4_1/libexec/bin/ccm", line 105, in 
>       cmd.run()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/ccm/3.1.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccmlib/cmds/node_cmds.py", line 233, in run
>       stdout, stderr, rc = self.node.nodetool(" ".join(self.args[1:]))   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/ccm/3.1.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccmlib/node.py",
>   line 812, in nodetool
>       return handle_external_tool_process(p, ['nodetool', '-h', 'localhost', '-p', str(self.jmx_port)] + cmd.split())   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/ccm/3.1.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ccmlib/node.py",
>   line 2072, in handle_external_tool_process
>       raise ToolError(cmd_args, rc, out, err) ccmlib.node.ToolError: Subprocess ['nodetool', '-h', 'localhost', '-p', '7100', 'status']
>   exited with non-zero status; exit status: 3;  stderr: Error connecting
>   to remote JMX agent! java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating
>   connection to: 10.1.8.166; nested exception is: 
>     java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)    at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.newClient(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2430)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.connect(NodeProbe.java:150)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.(NodeProbe.java:120)
>     at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.main(NodeCmd.java:1185) Caused
>   by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>     ... 12 more

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. If the community is to help you effectively we need a bit more information. Please edit the question to include your relevant source code. Also, please confirm that the listener is definitely active on the appropriate port on 10.1.8.166, and that you can definitely reach it through your network, since a connection problem seems to be indicated by the trace. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solved,
probably something went wrong with the connection because earlier i was fidgeting with a python application to connect to my cluster with datastax's driver.

a quick restart of the cluster solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exception creating connection to: 10.1.8.166; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed). showing unreachable. check network status and restart the same.